# Google Analytics 4 and Google Ads Hotel Campaigns not registering conversions

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api, google-analytics-4

Some time ago, we migrated Universal Analytics to Google Analytics 4. Since then, our Google Ads Hotel campaigns are not registering conversions, although we are still receiving conversions in Analytics.

We have correctly linked our Google Analytics and Google Ads accounts and we use gtag to trigger Google Analytics events.

We also have the automatic tagging (GCLID) and last click attribution method, but for some reason the conversions from Google Analytics never reach the Google Ads hotel campaigns.

Regarding the GCLID, does it need to be on all pages of the booking engine, or only on the initial screen where the first gtag event is launched?

We don't know what else to do to make it work again.